# DAX - How to Fill Empty Months with the Last Month of Quarter Value?

Tags: function, date, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I have the below scenario. I need to fill the M01 and M02 for each Quarter with the Last Month value. For example, on Q1-2021, I only have the last month value on my source (M03), so I need to fill M01 and M02 (yellow cells) with the M03 value, in other words, to replicate the M03 value to M01 and M02.

[image]

Any ideas or any example to help me on how can I build my DAX? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Add some sample data from your model.

Comment: Year Quarter Month  Actual   Headcount 
2020 Q1 M01  
2020 Q1 M02  
2020 Q1 M03  $675,494,072.80   658 
2020 Q2 M04  
2020 Q2 M05  
2020 Q2 M06  $737,891,514.45   657 
2020 Q3 M07  
2020 Q3 M08  
2020 Q3 M09  $595,218,397.71   673 
2020 Q4 M10  
2020 Q4 M11  
2020 Q4 M12  $771,515,301.30   673 
2021 Q1 M01  
2021 Q1 M02  
2021 Q1 M03  $561,700,924.73   674 
2021 Q2 M04  
2021 Q2 M05  
2021 Q2 M06  $625,245,105.37   674 
2021 Q3 M07  
2021 Q3 M08  
2021 Q3 M09  $639,514,984.71   674 
2021 Q4 M10  
2021 Q4 M11  
2021 Q4 M12  $645,650,009.48   674